# Why do we like LFSR and PN-sequence in FPGA?

Tags: fpga, shift-register, pn-sequence

Everybody has learnt that we like [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) in FPGAs because of its [simplicity](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/lfsr-linear-feedback-shift-register.html), *FPGA like* structure. [PN-sequence generator](http://www.thorsten-gaertner.de/vhdl/PRBS.pdf) is build up from LFSRs. (So we would think that this is FPGA-like generator...)

[image: PN-Sequence generator structure]

**BUT**

PN-seqence generator generates a new bit in each clock cycle, therefore we have to wait *n* clock-cycle to get an *n*-bit long word.

So to get a new PN-Sequence word in each clock-cycle we need to implement a much more complicated structure. This [repo](https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-lfsr) contains such an ["lfsr"](https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-lfsr/blob/master/rtl/lfsr.v), however the implemented design wont look alike an LFSR.

My questions:

- Am I right? (Is this statement correct?) It isn't a trivial task to generate PN-Sequence word in each clock-cycle.
- Why does the industry prefer the PN-sequence than other random generators?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the industry prefer the PN-sequence than other random
>   generators?

Because autocorrelation would give only one exact peak. Doing cross correlation of different PN code would give zero result, kind of selective receiving. You send  a sequence to DUT and you receive the response, used in radar, sonar, model identification,...etc

> It isn't a trivial task to generate PN-Sequence word in each
>   clock-cycle.

Not needed, as the transmitter sends a signal serially.

EDIT:

Let we have a boat with 4 sonars placed at sides, bow and aft. If each of them sends different PRBS, then doing cross-correlation of received signal with known code you'll selectively reconstruct the received response

EDIT2:
From your linked document, there is also a nice description of the application for these codes:

> A PRBS (Pseudo Random Binary Sequence) is a binary PN (Pseudo-Noise)
>   signal. The sequence of binary 1’s and 0’s exhibits certain randomness
>   and autocorrelation properties. Bit-sequences like PRBS are used for
>   testing transmission lines and transmission equipment because of their
>   randomness properties. Simple bit-sequences are used to test the DC
>   compatibility of transmission lines and transmission equipment.

Comment: The autocorrelation give only one exact peak in (almost) all the random generators.

Comment: Let's consider the random sequence is 1010101010 it will give several peaks, so not true that it gives only one.

Comment: The 1010101010 doesn't seem a random sequence...
 I mean all classic random generator structure generates random sequences which autocorrelation has one peak. Whats more the 1010101010 has only one peak in its period (ie 10)

Comment: I don't get it. For sure is a random sequence, I did choose it randomly. You should explain what are classic random generators. From my point of view a random generator is the Euro-jackpot extraction.

Comment: Other classical algorithms: PRBS, Gold-code, feedbacked-AES, (any feedbacked-chyper) counter+scrambler, feedbacked-scrambler, counter+AES ...

Comment: Those codes like PRBS, Gold-code, CDMA are orthogonal codes used for correlation as described earlier; AES, ciphers,..are used for encrypting. Not sure they are orthogonal, so this is a big difference. A random code is anything random, and there are no classical algorithms. Each one is for its specific task.

Answer (score 0):

We use LFSRs because it is a compact way of storing long sequences. The maximum length of the sequence is \$2^n - 1\$. Hence you can have a PN code of length a million that can be generated with 20 flip-flops.

For shorter codes you don’t need to use LFSRs. You can just store them in memory.

Comment: As I wrote the structure wont look alike an LFSR, if we want to generate a new PN-Sequence **word** in each clock-cycle.

Comment: @betontalpfa I’m not sure what you are asking exactly. Why would you need to generate the entire PN sequence each clock cycle. You get a new chip each clock cycle, which you XOR with the signal.

Comment: I have an AD9253 ADC connected to the FPGA. I want to test the serial digital data-lanes (the connection between the ADCs and the FPGA) The ADC can generate PN sequence as test pattern. The serial lanes working @800MHz, which cannot be handled inside an FPGA, so I have to check the PN sequence word by word

Comment: @betontalpfa Then just store the incoming signal in RAM (queue) or a shift register. You can compare the result with the PN code bit by bit as more data becomes available. You need to specify these things in your question. Both I and the other person who answered your question thought that you were asking about CDMA.

Answer (score 0):

> PN-sequence generator generates a new bit in each clock cycle, therefore we have to wait n clock-cycle to get an n-bit long word.

This is one way to do it.

It's also possible to design logic in the FPGA to generate multiple bits of the sequence at a time.

For example, if your flip flop outputs are called `x[1]`, `x[2]`, ... , `x[5]` like in your diagram, and your next output bit `y[0]` is given by `x[5]`. Let's say you want to generate two bits of the sequence at a time.  Well you know that the "future" output `y[1]` would be given by `x[4]`. So generating your two output bits at a time is easy.

But you also need to update the state by several cycles at a time.

In your 1-bit-at-a-time version, you have `x[1] = x[2] XOR x[5]`.

To generate two bits at a time, you work out what each state bit would be after two cycles of your serial version. Instead of getting `x[4]`, `x[5]` would be updated with the value from `x[3]`: `x[5] = x[3]`. And `x[4]` would get the value from `x[2]`: `x[4] = x[2]`. Similarly for `x[3]`.

The first couple bits are slightly trickier. You'll take the new state of `x[1]` from the serial machine and shift it along one step to get `x[2] = x[2] XOR x[5]`. And work out what `x[1]` will be after two cycles, it's `x[1] = x[1] XOR x[4]`.

Generating more bits at a time gets trickier, because you need to generate new inputs to the head of the shift register from bits that aren't even stored yet, but they can in fact all be calculated from the current state of the machine.